# Inverse of the greater-than relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

The *inverse* of $R$ is the relation $R^{-1}$ from $B$ to $A$ and is defined as $R^{-1}=\{(b,a)\in B\times A|(a,b) \in R\}$.

Let $G=\{(x,y)\in R \times R | x>y\}$.

Then, in *How to Prove It*,

$G^{-1}=\{(x,y)\in R \times R | (y,x)\in G\}$ (I'm confused here since it's of a different form from the definition given)

$G^{-1}=\{(x,y)\in R \times R | y>x \}$

$G^{-1}=\{(x,y)\in R \times R | x<y \}$

But according to the definition, shouldn't it be

$G^{-1}=\{(y,x)\in R \times R | (x,y) \in G \}$

$G^{-1}=\{(y,x)\in R \times R | x >y\}$

...

or should it be $G^{-1}=\{(y,x)\in R \times R | x<y\}$ since we are taking the $x$ and respective $y$ co-ordinates from $G$ and switching their them in the ordered pair $(y,x)$?

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is the same thing, fundamentally, and you've simply labeled them differently.

To help distinguish, let's let
$$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
G^{-1}_{1} =\{(x,y)\in \R \times \R \mid x<y \}
$$
and
$$
G^{-1}_{2} =\{(y',x')\in \R \times \R \mid y'<x'\}
$$

Goal: prove these are equal sets, i.e. $G^{-1}_{1} = G^{-1}_{2}$.

Take a pair $(x,y) \in G_{1}^{-1}$, and let $y' = x$ and $x' = y$, and hopefully the proof that $(x,y) \in G_2^{-1}$ (and the proof of the reverse inclusion) is immediate.

---

> should it be $G^{-1}=\{(y,x)\in R \times R | x<y\}$ since we are taking the $x$ and respective $y$ co-ordinates from $G$ and switching their them in the ordered pair $(y,x)$?

It should be
$$
G^{-1} = \{ (y,x) \in \R \times \R \mid x > y \}
$$
since the condition in the previous line is that $(x,y) \in G$, and we know from the definition of $G$ that $(x,y) \in G \iff x>y$.

The switching of coordinates only happens in the "first half" of the setbuilder notation as you notice in the opening:
$$
(a,b) \in R \iff (b,a) \in R^{-1}
$$

Comment: I've just made an edit to my question

Comment: I've just addressed said edit

Comment: Can you show how to get from

$G^{−1}=\{(y,x)∈R×R∣x>y\}$

to 

$G^{−1}=\{(x,y)∈R×R|x<y\}$

Comment: @airwick Simultaneously replace all the $x$s by $y$s and replace all the $y$s by $x$. If you only understand how to replace one variable at a time, it gets more tedious but still works: replace $x$ by $z$, then replace $y$ by $x$, then replace $z$ by $y$.

Comment: @airwick And one more thing, remember that $y>x$ is equivalent to $x<y$.